# jQuery remove a word into a string

Tags: jquery, html, string

I want to remove the first two word from multiple strings (date and month).

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  /* Get the text of the element I'm after */
  var niceText = $('div').text(),
    openSpan = '<span class="customOnlyFirstTwoWord">',
    closeSpan = '</span>';

  /* Make the sentence into an array */
  niceText = niceText.split(' ');

  /* Add span to the beginning of the array */
  niceText.unshift(openSpan);

  /* Add  as the 4th value in the array */
  niceText.splice(3, 0, closeSpan);

  /* Turn it back into a string */
  niceText = niceText.join(' ');

  /* Append the new HTML to the header */
  $('div').html(niceText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div> 22 may 2018 </div>
<div> 21 may 2018 </div>
<div> 20 february 2018 </div>
<div> 18 February 2018 </div>
```

But it does not work. Create a loop.
Do you have any suggestions or other solutions?

Comment: *But it does not work.* isn't much of a problem description. What does it do? Does it error? What's the error? Does it do something other than what you expected? What is it?

Comment: are you trying to display only year??

Comment: `$('div').text()` does not return an array of values.  If you want to change all the divs, you will have to loop over them.

Comment: The problem is that the result is a loop like this: 201822 marzo 201822 marzo 201822 marzo 201822 marzo 201822 gennaio 201821 marzo 2016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a little snippet that does what you want.

`22 may 2018` becomes `<span class="customOnlyFirstTwoWord"> 22 may </span> 2018`

> **Explanation**

I replace each div's html with [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

I wrap the first two words with a `span` using [`Array#splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

**Demo:**

```js
$('.test').html((_, html) => {
  var words = html.trim().split(' '); // Trim the html before splitting it
  words.splice(0, 0, '<span class="customOnlyFirstTwoWord">'); // Add the starting <span> at index 0
  words.splice(3, 0, '</span>'); // Add the ending </span> at index 3
  return words.join(' '); // Returns the new HTML
});

console.log($('.test').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"> 22 may 2018 </div>
<div class="test"> 21 may 2018 </div>
<div class="test"> 20 february 2018 </div>
<div class="test"> 18 February 2018 </div>
```

Comment: @Vixed Why would you link me this?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```js
$('div').html(function(_,html) {
    var mydate = html.trim().split(' ');
    return '<span class="customOnlyFirstTwoWord">'+mydate[0]+' '+mydate[1]+'</span> '+mydate[2];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> 22 may 2018 </div>
<div> 21 may 2018 </div>
<div> 20 february 2018 </div>
<div> 18 February 2018 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

$('div').text() , selecting all the divs in the dom. so use jquery each to iterate through. like following code.

```
var divs = $('div');
$.each(divs, function(){
 var string = $(this).text();
 var words = string.trim().split(' ');
 $(this).html('<span class="customOnlyFirstTwoWord">'+ words[0] + ' ' + words[1] +'</span>'  + ' ' + words[2]);
});
```

working demo here
https://jsfiddle.net/w3e4gpth/6/